# How can I remove a single cracked floor tile?

Tags: floor, tile

How can I remove a single damaged floor tile without damaging the surrounding tiles? Is there anything that will help the replacement tile from cracking in the same way?

Comment: this is relevant to my interests...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd grind/scrape away the grout first and then gently tap the middle of the tile with a screwdriver until it shatters and chip it out. It'll probably take a while to do it but you should be able to scrape/chip away the old thinset, apply new thinset then regrout.

best of luck !

Comment: Safety tip:  Wear eye protection while chipping the tile.

Comment: @Chris Cudmore - yes yes and yes !! this is definitely a time when you'll need safegy glasses or even a plastic face shield. Tile chips are thin, sharp as all get out, and they fly everywhere when struck.

Answer (score 9):

There is a dremel tool called the multi-max that I have used before. You can get a diamond attachment for it that will cut through grout like butter. Once you get the grout out you should be able pop up the tile and replace it.

Comment: after removing the grout, I'd drill a few holes in the tile surface two to "break it up" for easier removal

Answer (score 2):

YOu can cut out the grout with a grout saw. Be sure to not try to pry the tile up on the edges because you can easily damage the edge of the adjoining tiles. It you lightly tap the tile in the middle and break with a hammer, you can then remove the tile from the middle area, working to the outer edges.

You must remove all old thin-set by chipping or grinding it away. Apply new thinset to the back of the new tile and place. Wait approximately 12 -14 hours than grout the new tile into place.

Thanks
captainbay

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to remove the grout around the broken tile using a grout cutter. It’s important to make sure that you don’t chip the surrounding tile.You can then use a rotary tool or a utility knife to cut the down-ward facing tabs on three of the four sides.
Be sure to use the appropriate care and safety equipment when using the rotary tool or utility knife.Next carefully remove the broken [tile](http://www.tiles4all.co.uk/) by lifting and pulling away the uncut side.Then, remove the downward-facing tabs on three of the four sides of a new tile with a utility knife.Next apply a layer of adhesive and set the new tile into position.